# Cannot find AAD group using Identities ADO API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to replicate [this process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008606/how-to-programmatically-assign-reviewers-to-an-azuredevops-pullrequest) of adding reviewers to my ADO PRs and would like to specifically make it work for AAD groups. To my understanding, [this endpoint of adding reviewers to a PR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20reviewers/create%20pull%20request%20reviewer?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#definitions) requires a separate ID that is not a user's/group's Object ID (I call it an ADO ID). I am trying to use [this endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read%20identities?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#by-ids) to extract the ADO ID by providing an AAD group's Object ID. I have been successful in finding it for some groups but not others and I am not sure why that is. I have also been successful in using it to find users by specifying their email, but for groups it is a bit trickier. I've tried specifying the group's name but get the same results as using the Object ID. I do not have access to this group's identity id, identity descriptor, or subject descriptor. Please advise, thank you.

Comment: Hi @user13794359, how are things going? Have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it, and any progress, feel free to tell me.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT I have tried it and it does not seem to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **NOTE:** Before doing as the following method, make sure your organization has connected to the correct AAD where the group you want to add is in.

Directly search and add the AAD group to the Pull Request the following steps:

1. Execute the below API to search and get the details of the AAD group you want to add.

   - Request URI:

     ```
     POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/IdentityPicker/Identities?api-version=5.0-preview.1
     ```
   - Request body:

     ```json
     {
         "query": "{AAD group name}",
         "identityTypes": ["user", "group"],
         "operationScopes": ["ims", "source"],
         "options": {
             "MinResults": 5,
             "MaxResults": 40
         },
         "properties": [
             "DisplayName",
             "IsMru",
             "ScopeName",
             "SamAccountName",
             "Active",
             "SubjectDescriptor",
             "Department",
             "JobTitle",
             "Mail",
             "MailNickname",
             "PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName",
             "SignInAddress",
             "Surname",
             "Guest",
             "TelephoneNumber",
             "Manager",
             "Description"
         ]
     }
     ```
   - Response body:

     ```json
     {
         "results": [
             {
                 "queryToken": "addtovsts",
                 "identities": [
                     {
                         "entityId": "{entityId}",
                         "entityType": "Group",
                         "originDirectory": "aad",
                         "originId": "{AAD group ID}",
                         "localDirectory": null,
                         "localId": null,
                         "displayName": "{AAD group name}",
                         "scopeName": "{AAD name}",
                         "samAccountName": null,
                         "active": null,
                         "subjectDescriptor": null,
                         "department": null,
                         "jobTitle": null,
                         "mail": "{mail}",
                         "mailNickname": "{mailNickname}",
                         "physicalDeliveryOfficeName": null,
                         "signInAddress": null,
                         "surname": null,
                         "guest": false,
                         "telephoneNumber": null,
                         "description": null,
                         "isMru": false
                     }
                 ],
                 "pagingToken": ""
             }
         ]
     }
     ```
2. With the details returned from previous API, execute the below API to add the AAD group to the Pull Request.

   - Request URI:

     ```
     PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/reviewers?api-version=5.0
     ```
   - Request body:

     ```json
     {
         "entityId": "{entityId}",
         "entityType": "Group",
         "active": null,
         "department": null,
         "description": null,
         "displayName": "{AAD group name}",
         "guest": false,
         "id": "{AAD group ID}",
         "isAadIdentity": true,
         "isContainer": true,
         "isHosted": true,
         "isMru": false,
         "isRequired": false,  // 'true' will set the group as the Required Reviewer, 'false' is Optional Reviewer
         "jobTitle": null,
         "localDirectory": null,
         "localId": null,
         "mail": "{mail}",  // if you did not set mail, set the value same as 'mailNickname'
         "mailNickname": "{mailNickname}",
         "originDirectory": "aad",
         "originId": "{AAD group ID}",
         "physicalDeliveryOfficeName": null,
         "samAccountName": null,
         "scopeName": "{AAD name}",
         "signInAddress": null,
         "subjectDescriptor": null,
         "surname": null,
         "telephoneNumber": null,
         "vote": 0
     }
     ```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Bright Ran-MSFT. I have been able to find the AAD group with your suggestions. If I may ask, is there any documentation on the first request you linked? I have been unable to find anything on it. Also, do you know if all of these fields in the second request are actually necessary? I was looking at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20reviewers/create%20pull%20request%20reviewers?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) and found that a lot of the fields are now deprecated.

Comment: Hi @user13794359, For the first API, I also did not find any docs about it. Actually, I got it from the '`Network`' tab of the '`Developer tools`' on the browser (press `F12`).
From the '`Developer tools`', you can find many useful API that are not mentioned in the docs.

For the second requested API, not all the listed properties are necessary. Normally, you can omit the optional properties that the returned value is `null` from the first API.

Comment: a really good answer @BrightRan-MSFT. Where exactly did you figure out the options?